# Using CSS position sticky in VueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have been spending a lot of time on this issue I can't figure out why my CSS `position: sticky` doesn't work inside my template.

Most of my app is built using vuetify. I don't know if this interferes with the CSS `position: sticky` , but even when the component reaches the position, I never sticks.

```
<template>
    <v-sheet>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="2">
                <div class="side-panel">
                    <list_component class="side-panel-list"/>
                </div>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="10" class="pt-0 pb-0">
                <recipe_create_component/>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapState} from "vuex";

    export default {
        name: "production_tool_dashboard",
        extends: abstract,
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                ...
            })
        },
        components: {
            ...
        },
        data() {
           ...
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .side-panel-list {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .side-panel {
        top: 0;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        min-width: 240px;
        max-width: 240px;
        padding: 16px;
        border-right: solid 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
</style>
```

Any idea what this doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried to use `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Comment: Your css is using position: relative?

Comment: You should have position: sticky in your CSS. Press Ctrl + R to hard reload the browser. Probably the caching issue.

Comment: I've done a hard refresh, restarted de server... nothing new

Comment: try using `position: sticky !important;`

Comment: using `!important` dosen't resolve the issue.

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/buszmen/pen/YzXXxpw

Comment: Do you have `overflow: none` anywhere? @Buszmen 's example works because overflow is default. If you set his example to `.v-app {overflow: none}  .v-sheet {overflow: auto}` the stickiness doesn't work.

Comment: @seantunwin there isn't any overflow inside the component. Some component nested inside `<list_component>` use `overflow: hidden;` but that shouldn't affect the outer scope. have updated my code above so you can see the structure more clearly.

Comment: @Philx94 I had a similar issue with a Vuetify SPA, but I had `html` as `overflow: none` and had internal scrolling for some components. Sticky wouldn't work, so I resolved to `position: fixed; width: inherit`. It basically performed the same UX I was expecting.

Comment: Please share working demo or create StackBlitz. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the resulting generated code?

Comment: @Philx94 this may seem like a stupid question, but what browser are you using? sticky is not universally available: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem like this. One of the parent elements had an property overflow:hidden.

[css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/](https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/)

Comment: That was it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I made it work changing the side-panel-list height from % to vh, and setting the sizes of their parent containers. Something like this:

```
  <template>
    <v-sheet>
      <!-- this guy needs height. Note that vh and px works, % doesn't -->
      <v-row style="height: 50vh;">

        <!-- this guy also needs height -->
        <v-col style="height: 150vh;" >
          <div class="side-panel">
            <!-- this height does not work with % -->
            <list_component class="side-panel-list" style="height: 30vh">
          </div>
        </v-col>

        ...
      </v-row>
    </v-sheet>
  </template>
```

There is [this nice article](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46) about sticky positioning, that I would recommend too.

Comment: Especially note from the linked article that only-child sticky elements don't stick.

Answer (score 2):

So for me the tip from [@Александр Жилин](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13385010/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%96%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd) was perfect. In the end I made my sticky element work with this

```css
.parent-element{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.sticky-child{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}
```

Apperently it is very important for the parent element to have a **overflow: visible** as well as a **height** property set

Answer (score 1):

Please see to that any of the parent to the class, side-panel-list must not have position relative. It won't work if any of the parent has position relative.

Answer (score 1):

For sticky to work, the element must have siblings so it can remain fixed relative to them. In your code, you have placed the class on a child with no siblings. Try placing the class on your v-col instead since that element has siblings.

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="2" class="side-panel">  <!-- <<< class goes here!! -->
        <div>                            <!-- <<< not here -->
            <list_component class="side-panel-list"/>
        </div>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="10" class="pt-0 pb-0">
        <recipe_create_component/>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it CSS scoping? Try the following code

```css
<style scoped>
    .side-panel /deep/ .side-panel-list {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .side-panel {
        top: 0;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        min-width: 240px;
        max-width: 240px;
        padding: 16px;
        border-right: solid 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
</style>
```